# Lubuntu - WiFi connection/slow issues rtl8192cu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I have an issue with the Wifi disconnecting randomly.  I tried one of the previous questions recommendations.  However, now my connection is extremely slow (and still drops occasionally). (Some pages dont open and all downloads fail, which I think is as a result of the slowness.

Attached are some of tools results:

```
20.619277] rtl8192cu 1-8:1.0 wlxe84e06113b7b: renamed from wlan0
wayne@serv1:~$
```

`iwconfig` output:

```
wayne@serv1:~$ iwconfig
wlxe84e06113b7b  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Greybe household"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 38:F8:89:AC:41:9A   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:82   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

`lshw -c network` output:

```
wayne@serv1:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for wayne: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: c0
       serial: 00:24:1d:ec:8c:a7
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:f0100000-f013ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:8
       logical name: wlxe84e06113b7b
       serial: e8:4e:06:11:3b:7b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.4.7 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
wayne@serv1:~$
```

Id appreciate assistance.

Comment: hello , are you using embedded board (cubieboard/truck) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Im not sure what you are asking.  If youre asking whether I am using an embedded network card, the answer is no.  Its a "mini" wifi dongle.  The only description on the device is Edup.  I got it from a friend, so dont have a driver for it. (Im sure you can establish that I'm new to Linux).